# How to remove bad tags

Tags: php, html

I have problem, users have access to input form, and I want to remove all bad tags and JS like script, onClick etc...

Input is tinyMCE editor. Is there easy way or already made code for this, or I need to create function which removes all the "bad" entries?

Comment: `strip_tags` - http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: I know that function, it needs to manual input of allowed tags

Comment: you can configure tinyMCE, to allow or disallow tags

Comment: You should use HTMLPurifier or equivalents on the PHP side, you cannot do it through tinyMCE since that's client-side (I think) and can be modified.

Comment: yes, tinyMCE is jQuery plugin, so just disable it and post whatever you want.
thanks for purifir, will check it out

Comment: Could you not just use strip_tags and just allow the tags you want to be used?